# Java ConcurrentLinkedQueue behaving oddly

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, packets

I'm working on a project in which I add certain packets to a queue to be processed at a later time (the next 600ms tick processes all packets in queue).

However, I'm currently having trouble in that when two packets are received in the same cycle, the queue behaves very oddly.

at the top of my class I have

```
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<RSPacket> logicPackets;

public LogicDecoder() {
    super();
    logicPackets = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<RSPacket>();
    addDecodeable(new SendWalk());
}
```

And to add packets I have

```
    @Override
public void decode(RSPacket packet, Session session) {
    GameServer.get().logger().debug("LogicDecoder decoded " +  packet.getId() + " - " + packet.getLength() + " - " + packet.getOffset());
    for (RSPacket p : logicPackets) {
        if (p.getId() == packet.getId()) {
            logicPackets.remove(p);
            GameServer.get().logger().debug("Removed packet from queue with id " + packet.getId());
            break;
        }
    }
    logicPackets.add(packet);
    for (RSPacket p : logicPackets) {
        GameServer.get().logger().debug("LogicDecoder containsOnDecode " + p.getId());
    }
}
```

Here's the code that calls decode, this is the important bit of the decodeDecodables() method
NOTE: The same problem still occurs when I tried not using getConvertedPacket()

```
Decoder d = (Decoder) handler;
            P converted = (P) d.getConvertedPacket(packet, session);
            if (packet.getId() != PACKET.PING.getId()) {
                GameServer.get().logger().debug(packet.getId() + " -> " + converted.getId());
            }
            if (d.canHandle(converted, session) && d.preDecode(converted, session)) {
                d.decode(converted, session);
                return true;
            }
```

Lastly, here's how the queue is finally being used:

```
    @Override
public void onTick(Session session) {
    super.onTick(session);
    //GameServer.get().logger().debug("We have " + logicPackets.size() + " logicPackets to process");
    for (RSPacket p : logicPackets) {
        GameServer.get().logger().debug("pending packet id: " + p.getId());
    }
    RSPacket packet;
    while ((packet = logicPackets.poll()) != null) {
        //GameServer.get().logger().debug("LogicDecoder onTick Poll " + PACKET.forId(packet.getId()).name());
        if (!preDecode(packet, session) || !decodeDecodeables(packet, session)) {
            decodeFail(packet, session);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what is output when a packet with id 8 and a packet with id 59 are sent back to back.

```
[17:31:32] -> WorldDecoder recieved packet 8
[17:31:32] -> 8 -> 8
[17:31:32] -> LogicDecoder decoded 8 - 21 - 2
[17:31:32] -> LogicDecoder containsOnDecode 8
[17:31:32] -> WorldDecoder recieved packet 59
[17:31:32] -> 59 -> 59
[17:31:32] -> LogicDecoder decoded 59 - 21 - 12
[17:31:32] -> Removed packet from queue with id 59
[17:31:32] -> LogicDecoder containsOnDecode 59
```

As you can see, the first pass is fine, it adds packet 8 to the queue, then as the function is called again for packet 59, it decides that the packet we added before (packet 8) is now packet 59 and removes it before added itself. I honestly have no idea what is happening here.

Comment: You're probably modifying the id of the same packet and decoding it again. Post the code calling the decode method with 8 and 59.

Comment: Also you are probably not using the right data structure since you are traversing the queue. You might want to use a ``ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, RSPacket>``

Comment: I'm starting to think under the hood, it's still referencing back to a single packet object. I'm going to try making them cloneable and adding a clone to the queue instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the packet class to implement Cloneable I was able to fix this modifying this:

```
logicPackets.add(packet);
```

To this:

```
 logicPackets.add((RSPacket)packet.clone());
```